# Swift json time value to local time zone

Tags: json, swift, nstimezone

I have a json request that can produce two different types of time values.  Both ways it is in UTC time but I need to convert it to local time.

```
2015-12-01T13:05:33+00:00
```

or

```
1:05:33 PM
```

My attempt.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle //Set time style
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()
let localDate: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(time1)
print(localDate)
```

This what I get a as a result. 2000-01-01 19:05:33 +0000 if I use the 1:05:18 PM value.

The line for getting the json value.

```
let time1 = json["results"]["time1"].string!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, a couple of things things:

1. Parsing that RFC 3339/ISO 8601 string:

   ```
   let string = "2015-12-01T13:05:33+00:00"

   let rfc3339Formatter = NSDateFormatter()
   rfc3339Formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
   rfc3339Formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   let date = rfc3339Formatter.dateFromString(string)
   ```

   Note, I've set the locale (as per [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html)). But because the date string included time zone information, I can use the `Z` formatter character so that the time zone is correctly interpreted.
2. But `NSDate` objects do *not* have a time zone associated with them. In fact, if we do `print(date)` that we successfully parsed in the previous step, it will show us that `NSDate` in GMT/UTC, even if that original string was in a different time zone.

   A timezone is only meaningful when you use a formatter to convert this `NSDate` back to a new string to be presented to the user. So we can use a separate formatter to create the output string:

   ```
   let userDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   userDateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
   userDateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
   let outputString = userDateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
   ```

   Because this doesn't specify a time zone, it will create a string in the user's local time zone. And because we don't override the `locale` and use `.dateStyle` and `.timeStyle`, it will display it using the device's current localization settings when creating a string to be presented to the end-user.
3. Now, if you really are receiving a time in UTC (without the time zone included?! yikes, that's a really poor design to see that in JSON, IMHO), then you have to specify time zones:

   ```
   let string = "1:05:33 PM"

   let utcTimeStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   utcTimeStringFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
   utcTimeStringFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
   let time = utcTimeStringFormatter.dateFromString(string)
   ```

   Now that we have `time`, a `NSDate` containing the time represented by that string. But again, `NSDate` objects, themselves, don't have a time zone. Only when we convert that back to a string for the end user will we see the time in the local time zone:

   ```
   let userTimeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   userTimeFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
   let outputString = userTimeFormatter.stringFromDate(time!)
   ```

Comment: This was big help. Thank you for addressing both formats.  I was able to get it to work in either format.  Now all I have to right the code so that I can reuse it for all the times in the json file.

Comment: The key when using it repeatedly when parsing your JSON is to save those `NSDateFormatter` objects, so you're not repeatedly instantiating them. (So, for example, avoid creating an extension that instantiates the date formatter every time you call the method.) The process of instantiating a `NSDateFormatter` (or even changing the `dateFormat`/`dateStyle`/`timeStyle`) is relatively expensive,

Answer (score 0):

You can just try by setting your local timeZone or by setting `GMT`

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
```

> OR

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
```

Let me know, if you are still facing the error!